# Ubuntu big CPU usage - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I have laravel app on digitalocean on ubuntu and the site has been running fine for the last few months, but this morning at about 6 AM the CPU usage went up to 100% when I used htop and atop command it shows that the problem is somewhere in PHP, after investigating I found that PHP is running multiple times and running queue:worker.

for queue I use supervisor, bellow is supervisor code

the queue worked fine before the CPU was at 100%

```
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d

command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work

autostart=true

autorestart=true

user=root

numprocs=8

redirect_stderr=true

stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/worker.log
```

[image: HTOP]
[image: ATOP]

Comment: `numprocs=8` - did you only expect one? If you run `ps -aef --forest` you will see they all branch from the `hypervisord` process which points to your config defining it should spin up 8 sub processes.

Comment: I reduced the `numrprocs` to 1 but still PHP takes about 7% - 12% CPU in `top`. The CPU in the dashboard has shrunk in digitalocean, but when I want to go to the page it says `HTTP ERROR 500 This page is not working`

Comment: The worker is used for the [`queues` system](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) in Laravel which would have no effect on the main application because its stateless - ie, it can run without it! Your dispatches just won't execute if it isn't running. Turn on debug mode (error reporting) to debug your application further. The two are likely unrelated issues. I would then suggest you code review and figure out if you can optimise any of the code to reduce overall memory and CPU usage.

Comment: Also, you will need to restart the hypervisord processes for it to take effect with `supervisorctl restart whatever-you-named-it:*`. You can again verify only one subprocess with `ps -aef --forest`.

Comment: If it’s the queue, you should definitely know what the queue has processed the last hour or so. Telescope can be used, though you have to sandbox it in a live environment and secure it in a decent way to inspect if something’s going sideways ..